# Git list tags from a certain period

Tags: bash, git

I know I can list all tags and their creator dates this way:

```
git tag -l --format='%(refname) %(creatordate)' --sort=creatordate
```

But what if I am only interested in tags created in the year 2008? Or maybe tags created from 2. 3. 2015 to 6. 8. 2016? Is there a way to do this using git only? Or do I have to parse the output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`git for-each-ref refs/tags/`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-for-each-ref). For example list tags with their creation date in short simple greppable format and filter:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format='%(refname) %(creatordate:short)' | grep 2008-
```

If you need better filtering than simple `grep` print dates in more fine-grained parseable format and parse the output with your own script:

```
git for-each-ref refs/tags/ --format='%(refname) %(creatordate:iso-strict)'
```

For the list of possible date formats see [`git rev-list --date=<format>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list#git-rev-list---dateltformatgt).